# Projector Headlights very Dim

Tags: headlight

I have these projector headlights with H4 bulbs and a black background.  I tried them for the first time and they are really dim and not bright at all, I could barely see! Anyways, I bought these headlights and they are dim there is a little bulb under the h4 headlights with wires out of them if I wired them would the light get brighter? I also bought the recommended wiring harness supposedly supposed to make it brighter. Will the harness be okay, or should I wire the smaller bulbs too?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend ensuring the wiring harness ground is working effectively.  Quite often dim headlights result from poor grounding.  There should be a ground wire bolted or screwed to a clean metal surface.